# Python/tkinter OptionMenu method

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I continue to learn more about using tkinter and OO methods, but I could use a hint.  I've written myself a general method for creating a drop-down menu (OptionMenu) in tkinter:

```
class CustomDropDown(tk.OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent, *kwargs ):
        tk.OptionMenu.__init__(self, parent)
        for attribute, value in kwargs.items():
            try:
               self[attribute]     = value
            except:
                raise
```

And, its use in my main method is:

```
#       create drop-down menus  
choices                         = list( commonSerifList.keys() )
tkvar                           = StringVar(master)
tkvar.set(choices[0]) # set the default option
dropdownWidget                  = {}
dropdownWidget["fontType"]      = CustomDropDown(
            master, tkvar, *choices)
```

which returns the error:

```
typeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'variable' and 'value'
```

For reference, I started with lines of code which I had hoped to generalize to accept any list for the dropdown menu (which worked just fine):

```
# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar                           = StringVar(root)
# Dictionary with options
choices                     = list( commonSerifList.keys() )
tkvar.set('agencyfb') # set the default option
OptionMenu() 
popupMenu                       = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
Label(mainframe, text="Choose a size").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)

# on change dropdown value
def change_dropdown(*args):
    print( tkvar.get() )

# link function to change dropdown
tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)
```

But, I wanted to be able to pass in the dropdown list, default value, and .place position data in order to build any number of dropdown menus.

Comment: Why are you calling `tk.OptionMenu.__init__(self, parent)` instead of just `tk.OptionMenu(self, parent)` or using `super` ?

Comment: Please don't section your code like that. Instead create [mcve] singlepiece.

Comment: Do you want me to re-write my submission, Nae, per your comment?  No trouble.  Please advise.  For JacobIRR, your question points to my ignorance.  I will try it.

Comment: You can't initialize an `OptionMenu` object without passing 2 arguments as `variable` and `value`. In the `tk.OptionMenu.__init__(self, parent)` line, the arguments are missing.

Comment: Hi, Nae.  Thank you for your continued support.  I had created a method for generic button creation, class CustomButton(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent)
        for attribute,value in kwargs.items():
            try:
                self[attribute] = value
            except:
                raise

Comment: Kind of hard to write the code properly in the comments section here, but hopefully you'll get my drift.  Anyway, this works with any list of valid arguments to the CustomButton method, such as 'text', 'command', etc., without explicit articulation of the variables passed to the method.

Comment: @JacobIRR It's standard to call the `__init__` method. Both the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) and [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/scrolledtext.py) do this.

Comment: You can always [edit].